# How to convert a ReactNode to a string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to convert this code to a string keeping Tailwind CSS and other things intact. I am using Next with typescript and tailwind css.

Input :

```
export default function Header_1() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-aui_primary text-aui_text h-12 w-full flex justify-between items-center px-4">
      Header
      <button className="w-20 h-8 bg-aui_accent text-md font-semibold text-aui_text_accent flex justify-center items-center text-center rounded-sm">
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Output I want:

```
"<div className="bg-aui_primary text-aui_text h-12 w-full flex justify-between items-center px-4">
  Header
  <button className="w-20 h-8 bg-aui_accent text-md font-semibold text-aui_text_accent flex justify-center items-center text-center rounded-sm">
    Login
  </button>
</div>"
```

I have tried **using `renderToString(<MyComponent />)`** but it isn't working as I am using client component and also tried the alternative suggested on the react website but that also didn't do the job.

I have used `renderToString` as follows :
variant.component will give me Header_1 as output.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (variant) {
      const html = renderToString(<variant.component />);
      console.log(html);
    }
  }, []);
```

ERROR I am getting:
Internal Error: do not use legacy react-dom/server APIs. If you encountered this error, please open an issue on the Next.js repo.

**using `flushSync`**

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

export const renderToString = (component: React.ReactNode) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const root = createRoot(div);
  flushSync(() => {
    root.render(component);
  });
  return div.innerHTML;
};

export default function Preview({ variant }: { variant: Variants }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (variant) {
      const myOutput = renderToString(<variant.component />);
      console.log(myOutput);
    }
  }, []);

  return(
  /// code
  )
}
```

ERROR : Warning: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. React cannot flush when React is already rendering. Consider moving this call to a scheduler task or micro task.

Comment: Show the code how did you use `renderToString`?

Comment: Added it to the existing question. Please have a look !

Comment: Have you tried this https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToStaticMarkup#rendertostaticmarkup

Answer (score 0):

According to react documentation this should work...

```js
import { React } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

export const renderToString(component: React.ReactNode) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const root = createRoot(div);
    flushSync(() => {
      root.render(component);
    });
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Edit: seems like your issue is tied to running it in a useEffect, here is a suggestion.

Since you only need it to run on mount there is no need for a useEffect, we can use state to for the generated html string and check that it has value on each render.

```js
export default function Preview({ variant }: { variant: Variants }) {
  const [innerHTML, setInnerHTML] = useState(null);

  console.log({ innerHTML });

  if(!innerHTML) {
    const html = renderToString(<variant.component />);
    if(html) {
      setInnerHTML(html);
    } else {
      setInnerHTML('Something went wrong!');
    }
  }

  return(
  /// code
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. I had tried this earlier and this was the issue I was facing. Please have a look !

Comment: Updated the answer to account for your question changes @KrishPatel